# Is there a way to output a code coverage file for a native C++ app each time I run it in VS2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, code-coverage

I'm currently going through the coverage of my code, and I need a .coverage file to view it. I have found out how to retrieve a coverage file for native C++ through this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cellfish/archive/2008/11/16/native-c-code-coverage-reports-using-visual-studio-2008-team-system.aspx)

And they follow these steps in order to output a .coverage file:

> 1. First of all your project must be compiled using the /PROFILE link option. If you bring up your project properties it can be found here:
>      Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Advanced -> Profile
> 2. The profiler tools can then be found in the following directory:
>      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools
> 3. You need to add some instrumentation code to your EXE or DLL file and that is done with this command:
>      vsinstr.exe  /COVERAGE
> 4. This will copy the original file to an ".orig"-file and create a new file with the original name that contains instrumentation code needed to gather coverage data.
>      Now start the listener with this command:
>      VSPerfMon.exe /COVERAGE /OUTPUT:
> 5. Now run your EXE or some test suite that uses the file you want to calculate coverage for.
> 6. The listener started in step four (4) will not stop by it self once your test suite is finished so you have to stop in manually using this command (from a second command prompt):
>      VSPerfCmd.exe /SHUTDOWN
> 7. When the listener has stopped you just drag-n-drop the created ".coverage"-file into Visual Studio and you can view the results.

I'm wondering if there is a way to automate this so that this tool will output a .coverage file to the same location each time I run the program. This will make obtaining my code coverage percentage much easier and faster. Anyone know how to make run with any C++ program in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: VS 2012 has a new coverage tool that doesn't require any of those steps.  The only requirement of the new tool is that .pdb files need to be discoverable when collecting coverage data (previously they were required for instrumentation and analysis).  Check out my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983003/can-we-get-native-c-code-coverage-in-vs2012-or-vs2010-without-mstest/14995243#14995243) about this very thing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried using CodeCoverage.exe's collect command, and it spat out its usage. I then ran the program, it finished successfully, and I checked the output location in Windows Explorer and it didn't output the .coverage file. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The output switch should be relative to the CWD, so if you did `CodeCoverage.exe collect /output:foo.coverage foo.exe`, you should expect to see the file immediately in the directory you ran the command from.  It gets created when collection starts, but the coverage data only gets flushed to disk at certain times (like shutting down collection).  Note that unlike the old coverage tools, there is no "instrument" step; the collect command runs the program you give it and instruments it on-the-fly during collection.

Comment: Hmm, I'm running the command in the same working directory as Visual Studio (right clicking the project folder -> Open in Command Prompt) and running that exact command (except with my .exe file), and I'm not receiving any .coverage file. I'm running VS2012 with Update 3, is Update 3 compatible with the CodeCoverage tool? I don't understand why I can't get it to work. Also, thank you for trying to help me out.

Comment: Given that you can't write to anything under Program Files unless you're running in an elevated context, my guess is that the coverage file was redirected due to filesystem virtualization.  I would supply a full path for the output option to a directory your user can write to.